# Generating checksum value of a file in S3. But every time it is giving a new value even though no change to the file

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sha

I have an AWS Lambda snippet like this. The purpose is to generate the checksum of the file of the given URL. The URL is from an S3 bucket. The checksum generating and printing, that is fine. But every time I execute the lambda, a NEW checksum is generated, that is the issue. As there is no change to the file, I am EXPECTING the same checksum value every time.

```
    import hashlib
    import requests


    def checksum(url):
        BUF_SIZE = 65536  # lets read stuff in 64kb chunks!
        m = hashlib.sha256()
        r = requests.get(url)
        for data in r.iter_content(BUF_SIZE):
            m.update(data)
        return m.hexdigest()


    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        url = "https://xxx-xxx-xxxxx-us-east-1-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/HDBAPA104APAL_Barbapapa_xxx_servicing_25_clip_submission_5dot1.mov"
        print(f"{checksum(url)}")
```

Comment: Do you have to do it via the URL?  Where does the event come from (i.e. S3 PutObject, etc)?

Comment: @stdunbar I get the bucket name and file name from the event. Then I compose the URL. The event is coming from a Step Function.

Comment: Is the URL a public object?  What is `r.status_code`?  `requests.get` will not generate an exception for a 403 error, meaning you'll be returning the digest for the error page, something that changes on every call.